# CDI interceptor Scope annotation

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, cdi, java-7

Context:

`Wildfly 8.1.0` with `CDI 1.2`

According to the `CDI` specification for `CDI1.2`, you do not need to declare a cdi in `beans.xml` if it is annotated `@Priority(somepriorityvalue)`

However, the following cdi interceptors are never called unless I add the `@Dependent` annotation

```
@RequiresLoggedInAccount
@Interceptor
@Priority(Interceptor.Priority.APPLICATION)
public class MyInterceptor {

  @AroundInvoke
  public Object intercept(final InvocationContext ic) throws Exception {
    //intercept something and then...
    return ic.proceed();
  }
}
```

and the interceptor binding:

```
@Inherited
@Documented
@InterceptorBinding
@Target({METHOD, TYPE})
@Retention(RUNTIME)
public @interface RequiresLoggedInAccount {
}
```

Note that the interceptor binding and interceptor are defined in a different jar module from where they are used (so the purpose for the @Priority).

Is it something I have overlooked? Why must I add the `CDI`'s `@Dependent` scope for the interceptor to kick?

Is it because I have specifically stated in the `beans.xml` `bean-discovery-mode="annotated"`

Comment: WildFly 8.1 ships with Weld 2.1.  Did you manually upgrade to Weld 2.2?

Comment: @JohnAment Oh, damned. It does ships with CDI 1.1, does that explain the behaviour?

Comment: would this also explain why annotating a single interceptor with two different InterceptorBindings make the interceptor not get loaded?

Comment: I'm not sure multiple interceptor bindings is supported by the spec.  Yes, if you haven't manually upgraded that would explain what you're seeing.  The list of bean defining annotations was expanded in 1.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WildFly 8.1 ships with Weld 2.1.x (i forget x, but 2.1 is CDI 1.1 compliant).  You can apply patches to it to upgrade to Weld 2.2 which is CDI 1.2 compliant and this issue should go away for you.

The behavior you're seeing is consistent with CDI 1.1 implementations.